# Isapi filter to apache module

Tags: c++, c, linux, apache, iis

How to convert  isapi filter(c++) to an apache module(c for Linux).Could you provide some code or link please.

Answer (score 2):

IIS has different extension API from Apache, so there is no easy way to convert an ISAPI filter to Apache module.

All you could do is to learn how to extend Apache and manually rewrite the code.